# Unset operation failing for MongoMapper model, cannot delete / remove key from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

We're on mongodb 2.0.0, mongo gem 1.4.1, mongo_mapper 0.9.2, rails 3.0.6.

We love MongoMapper, but we need helping resolving one nasty issue: we have a key carried over from some testing, but invoking obj.unset fails to do anything.

Specifically, we are trying to remove an "id" key (not "_id") because it's causing MM to treat obj.id as different from obj._id, which we don't want.

After clearing out the database, we ran these commands from a controller which does nothing else: (We also tried running the same code from the rails console, but it also fails.)

```
logger.info "#{Game.keys.keys.inspect}"
Game.unset({}, :id)
logger.info "#{Game.keys.keys.inspect}"
Game.unset(:id)
logger.info "#{Game.keys.keys.inspect}"
```

Output:

```
["jackpot", "players", "created_at", "puzzles", "ended_at", "player_index", "updated_at", "log", "_id", "id", "join_code", "puzzle_index"]
["jackpot", "players", "created_at", "puzzles", "ended_at", "player_index", "updated_at", "log", "_id", "id", "join_code", "puzzle_index"]
["jackpot", "players", "created_at", "puzzles", "ended_at", "player_index", "updated_at", "log", "_id", "id", "join_code", "puzzle_index"]
```

Current keys defined in our Game model:

```
  key :players, Array, :default => []
  key :player_index, Integer, :default => 0
  key :puzzles, Array, :default => []
  key :puzzle_index, Integer, :default => 0
  key :join_code, String, :default => nil
  key :jackpot, Integer, :default => 0
  key :log, Array, :default => []
  key :created_at, Time
  key :updated_at, Time
  key :ended_at, Time, :default => nil
```

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you possibly still be on Mongo 1.4.1? There are a number of bugs and performance issues in that version. First step seems to upgrade to the latest version of the database and MM and then see if your problem persists.

Comment: I think "mongo" refers to the gem version, 1.4.1 is recent.  Also, this question was answered on the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/20ea194868195c3e  TL;DR unset works on the database only, but MM always remembers what keys it has seen and saves new docs with them.  Need to reload doc and/or restart the server.  Related to issue #195 https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/195

Comment: Thanks, both. Yes, "mongo" refers to the gem. We'll update the question to clarify this. Plastic Chicken, we tried restarting the Mongo server and app server, but maybe we need to reload the doc, too. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, Plastic Chicken, assuming this works, please respond as an answer so we can credit you.

Comment: We ran the unset commands from both rails console and from 
the controller. We then restarted both Passenger and MongoDB, but no 
difference. We also tried just restarting Passenger. 
Is there something else we need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It pains us to post the answer since this solidifies our status as "morons, idiots, fools, noobs, Jay Leno fans," but in case anyone else bumps into the same issue: while our model directory was clean in the dev environment, the model dir in the production environment contained old test files ... which contained an old model with the "id" key.

Obviously, removing the old files and the old models solved everything, though we're left with staggering bruises to our egos and to our heads (from excessive banging against the walls).

Comment: :) This is a nice heads up for someone debugging a mongodb.